# What were the six Mubarak assassination attempts?

Tags: egypt, assassination

Today there's a story about Mubarak in the hospital. He ruled Egypt since 1981 but was overthrown in 2011. Wikipedia says he survived six assassination attempts during that 30-year period, however it mentions only a couple and the references given don't provide much detail.  What were those attempts and how were they thwarted or failed, and who was behind them?

Comment: @Dan-the-man I've removed the [tag:Hosni-Mubarak-Egypt] tag. This tag is unlikely to be used again. Please favor existing tags.

Comment: @Luke, What do you mean? He was a leader in a country. http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-to-do-with-tags-that-have-multiple-meanings

Comment: http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/294/961

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The state security service is the one who foiled the assassinations attempts.

I think they are four attempts (may be there are more attempts)

1. the most famous one was in 27 june 1995 In the Ethiopian capital Addis Ababa.

Mustafa Hamza, a member of the Al Qaeda organization is the main suspect in the assassination attempt on Mubarak in Addis Ababa. But the bullets did not penetrate the body of the President armored car.

2. in France.
3. inside Egypt in a city called Fayoum.

There was an Islamist group planned to assassinate him, but were stopped by security

4. in 1999 inside Egypt in a city called Port Said.

During the visit of Mubarak to the city of Port Said, and while his car was on the road, a man called Abualaraby rush to his car but the security men killed him immediately and the security men said that he was carrying a knife, but others believe that he was just an ordinary simple man.

Comment: Mubarak was wounded during Sadat's assassination in 1981. I'm not sure if the Wikipedia article includes this one or not.

Comment: Thanks, any idea what the other two attempts might have been?  Also, while this identifies the location, it still leaves unanswered who attempted it, what the attack was, and how it failed or was prevented.

Answer (score 5):

There were undoubtably numerous plots that made it to various stages. Where such a plot progresses to qualifying as an "attempt" is probably mostly up to the speaker.

For example if it was the security services speaking, they'd have incentive to make themselves look good by being a bit generous as to what qualifies as an attempt. On the other hand, someone speaking for Mubarak himself might want to downplay how little he was liked, and thus might be more stingy in what qualifies.

So to answer this question precisely, you'd really have to go to the person who gave wikipedia that number of six and ask them.

Answer (score -2):

Buddy of mine from Egypt said that Mubarak had only four attempts on his life, not six. He may be wrong though. the other two might not have been publicized.

Comment: This also seems to agree with the accepted answer, which has details concerning these attempts.